# center a html div (margin 0 auto help)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a footer menu but it is not positioning correctly. I have tried a margin auto 0 which is working for the main container div, but doesn't work on the footer. Please help. Thanks in advance.

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

css code

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container {
height: 300px;
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border: 5px solid #dbdbda;
}

/*footer*/
/*
#footer {
margin: 0 auto;
}
*/
#footer ul {
font-size: 10px;
list-style: none;
}

#footer li {
float: left;
}

#footer li a {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
color: #323232;
}

#footer li a:hover {
color: #dbdbdb;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? BTW, the footer code is commented out.

Comment: It seems not very clear if you want to center the footer as a whole, or if you want to center the footer menu links

Comment: So you need to center the div with id footer or the ul that is inside the footer? Because the only way to center the div is to set a width like others mentioned below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `display:inline-block` to ul tag inside your footer and `text-align:center` to footer.

This will help to be independent from number of li's in footer. Otherwise, you must give width to your footer, which isn't correct in this situation, because you can need to add some element to footer and changing width everytime isn't nice solution.

See updated [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vMZSV/)

Answer (score 3):

`margin: 0 auto` doesn't work without `width`, try to set `fixed width`, for example `width: 100px;`

Comment: Question is to center the footer. By setting the width, you'll have to know the exact number of pixels of the footer in order to center it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Give your footer a fixed width, or it won't know what "center" actually means in relation to the rest of the page.

```
#footer {
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Question is to center the footer. By setting the width, you'll have to know the exact number of pixels of the footer in order to center it this way.

Comment: If you have a footer div of indefinite width and you want to center it *aligned to something else with a fixed width*, how would you propose to do it? Centering the footer is not the same as centering a number of links in the footer.

Comment: But you are right, the answer @Chuck Norris provides is no doubt correct if the footer links needs to be centered in the page and there's no future background etc for the footer. I guess we interpreted the question differently.

Comment: Hmm, that is also how I interpreted it first, but he wants to center the 'footer menu', so I suppose he wants the links to be centered. If he wants the footer to be centered the same way as the container, I would suggest putting the footer IN the container instead.

Comment: Yep - might very well be so. Either way I'm sure he's gotten the help he needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css,

```
#footer {
text-align:center;
}
#footer ul {
font-size: 10px;
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
width:500px;

}
```